How to resolve ECONNRESET while installing Angular?
I'm trying to install angular using the command: npm install -g @angular/cli
and I get the following error:
(https://i.sstatic.net/j5xwG.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/WnK8I.png)
I already tried to fix this error without any luck. I tried some things such as:

Check my internet connection and network connectivity
ping registry.npmjs.org
Clear the npm cache
Disable my antivirus (firewall)
Check my proxy settings
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
Upgrade Node and NPM
node -v
v18.20.2
npm -v
10.5.0
Check my.npmrc file
# .npmrc
legacy-peer-deps=true

